# Are the amynodontidae being slandered?

Tags: ancient-greek, scientific-names

Wikipedia says that the name of this extinct family of rhino-like animals means "threatening tooth," referencing [this page](http://research.amnh.org/paleontology/perissodactyl/concepts/glossary#amynodon), but that page actually says "Greek: to ward off/threaten (amynos) teeth (odontos), reference to large tusks." (Googling shows lots of other material that seems to have been copied from wikipedia.) But LSJ's [definition of ἀμύνω](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%80%CE%BC%CF%8D%CE%BD%CF%89) makes reference only to defense, not threats. Bailly has basically the same definition, although they also include "punir," while Pape mentions revenge and Cunliffe succor.

Is wikipedia slandering the amynodontidae by making them out to be violent aggressors? They're no longer around to defend themselves. Plus they're kind of cute.

Comment: You got a point:  ἄμυνα is defense, revenge, nothing close to aggression... Just like defense forces and departments of defense...

Comment: I've edited the WP article.